# Set parent to wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf

Earlier we have used usercontrols to show modal dialogs.
Now decided to implement it as wpf window.
And i have one problem.
I want to set parent of window into constructor of my modaldialogwindow.
I know hwnd of my parent window(can get it by process name)
and i don't know how to get hwnd of child window(my modal dialog) into const of it.

Or I need to setparent for this window like this

```
    var window = new ModalDialogWindow(Properties.Resources.ChangeLabelPartDialogTitle, ChangeLabelPartDialog);
Setparent(Childhwnd,parenthwnd);
           window.ShowDialog();
```

But I also dont know how to get hwnd of this window before `showdialog()` method

Comment: Could you add a parameter to the constructor of ModalDialogWindow to pass in the value of the window that is spawning the dialog?

Comment: Why do you know hwnd? You can set owner directly of child window by setting it's Owner property to parent window.

Comment: It was the first solution. But it doesnt work in our situation. We have situation when modal dialog are loosing it's parent(owner)
that's why i decide to use winapi

Answer (score 7):

Handle of the parent window is all you need. To set the parent for your dialog window you can use System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper class as shown in the code below:

```
public partial class ModalDialogWindow : Window
{
    public ModalDialogWindow(IntPtr parentWindowHandle)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var interop = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        interop.EnsureHandle();
        // this is it
        interop.Owner = parentWindowHandle;
    }
}
```